# How can I detect all changes made from a default install or point in time?

Tags: package-management, system

I am trying to learn Ubuntu (and Linux in general) on a much deeper level right now and am having a nightmare tracking changes - in particular with the package management system.

Is there any (relatively easy) way I can snapshot the file system and then at a later date compare all changes that have been made since the initial snapshot?

Or, if not file system, can you recommend any technique or program that can help me to achieve this?

Please note that I am looking for an answer that can help me to understand the system deeper and to learn more, I am not looking for how to fix/uninstall. I use virtualisation a lot and can easily rollback if I need to.

---

If anyone is interested why I am asking this question or if anyone else is tryign to learn...

I installed Ubuntu Server and everything works great - I then wanted to try to install and learn X and how different shells work, so, I typed `apt-get install kde`, and even though I later did `apt-get autoremove kde`, there still appears to be hundreds of packages installed that are no longer needed or didn't get removed.

Putting the packages aside, there are bigger system level changes that have occurred such as the system calling startx (I guess) at the startup, but, without KDE, it just freezes... I managed to fix with adding the "text" option to grub, however, considering a default install of Ubuntu without X doesn't have this, I feel like I have cheated and I would like to know how/where X is being invoked.

Comment: you should run `sudo apt-get purge kde` if it complains kde is not installed, run this `sudo apt-get install kde && sudo apt-get purge kde` then, `sudo apt-get autoremove` followed by `sudo apt-get autoclean` and then `sudo apt-get update` and finally `sudo apt-get upgrade` just to get it out of the way as well.

Comment: If you don't have another shell like gnome shell, compiz, ubuntu-desktop, lxde, xfce etc installed, you won't have a shell for x after removing kde because ubuntu-server does not come with an x server or GUI type shell, display manager, or window manager so you may have to install one if one is not already installed. For a bare bones minimal window manager for your xsession, you may want to check out fluxbox or icewm.

Comment: @mchid Thanks, I wasn't really looking at any programs in particular, I am just trying to learn how all these individual programs snap together and work! But, I will certainly take a look at the two you mention - thanks. Also, many thanks for those apt-get commands... I love how easy it makes installing stuff - I just seem to be having a bit of a nightmare removing and getting the order of the uninstall/commands correct... I didn't know I could call autoremove/autoclean without specifying a package.

Answer (score 3):

**For snapshots:**

you can use, snapper or backintime-common. Here's how to install both of these:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install snapper backintime-common
```

[more info on snapper can be found here](http://snapper.io/)

[more info on backintime can be found here](https://backintime.readthedocs.io)

[and this ubuntugeek article on backintime](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/back-in-time-a-simple-backup-tool-for-ubuntu.html)

---

**To checkout your dpkg logs:**

Your system changes such as all the package changes updates and installed/uninstalled packages are listed in /var/log/dpkg.log. Open a terminal and execute the following commands to take a look at what you have here:

First, make a directory to work in:

```
mkdir ~/dpkg
```

change your current directory:

```
cd ~/dpkg
```

copy your dpkg log files into the new directory:

```
sudo cp /var/log/dpkg.log* ~/dpkg
```

change the owner of the files to your username:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/dpkg
```

unzip the compressed logfiles (if any). BTW it might say "unknown suffix -- ignored" and that's okay:

```
gunzip dpkg.log.*
```

list the files in your directory

```
ls
```

The newest entries will be found in dpkg.log, the oldest entries will be found in the file with the largest number at the end of the filename (dpkg.log.2 for example or dpkg.log.3 and so on).

To read the most recent changes (file dpkg.log):

```
less dpkg.log
```

or, from any directory:

```
less ~/dpkg/dpkg.log
```

To read dpkg.log.2 for example:

```
less dpkg.log.2
```

and so on. Press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit a file.

Most other log files can be found in /var/log as well. To list the contents of /var/log:

```
ls /var/log
```

---

Alternatively, you could install ubuntu on a btrfs partition rather than use the default ext4 filesystem. Unlike windows (which is only installable on NTFS), Ubuntu can be installed on many different filesystem types. The default is ext4, there is ext3, ext2, btrfs and a couple others available as well if I'm not mistaken. You may be interested in checking it out for a future ubuntu install.

If you install ubuntu using a btrfs partition instead of an ext4 fylesystem, you can then install these helpful tools after installation of the operating system:

```
sudo apt-get install btrfs-tools* apt-btrfs-snapshot
```

Snapshots are made each time you use apt-get so you can always revert back after installing or uninstalling software.

[official ubuntu documentation can be found here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs)

[btrfs vs ext4 benchmarking on kernel 3.15 can be found here (not ubuntu specific)](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_315_hddfs&num=3)

Comment: I changed a typo for sudo cp /var/log/dpkg.log* ~/dpkg if it matters

Comment: Thanks! As I tried to make clear in the comments to the other answer... whilst the package management is highly related to my problems right now, I am interested in looking at complete changes from two different points in time (as a package could create a config/script as part of the install or just running that wasn't actually part of the package manifest).... So, I think this rules out dpkg.log, however, snapper and back-in-time look like the perfect tools for what I want to do! (Just need to figure out how to use from CLI or another machine and set up a workflow now!)

Comment: ... I'll keep question open for a day or so, in case anyone can recommend any other tools - but if nothing else comes up, happy to give this one the mark! ... Thanks

Comment: @wilhil when you run a `purge` command instead of `remove` such as `sudo apt-get purge kde` the config files are removed, simply running `sudo apt-get remove kde` only removes the software but leaves the configuration intact in case you decide to reinstall it some day. Checking dpkg can tell you exactly what was installed along with kde so that you can possibly run the purge command on those packages as well to return the system to what it was before kde installation, including configurations etc.

Comment: Ahh, got you! Just curious though, does purge run scripts/is it configured on a per package basis or does it simply delete files that were installed as part of the package manifest? For example, if I install something that invokes a script and creates a bunch of config files, will those files be removed as they were not in the original packages?

Comment: @wilhil system conf files for the specific applications you are running the command for should be removed, however sometimes there are hidden configuration files in your home directory. use the command `ls -A` to show all files in a directory including hidden files. use the command `ls -A ~/` to list all files in the home directory. .mozilla for example contains all the firefox config files. Also, look for config files in ~/.config `cd ~/.config && ls -A`. To remove a file, run: `sudo rm filename` to remove an entire directory (folder) use: `sudo rm -R nameofdirectory` use real names ofcourse

Comment: @wilhil **BE CAREFULL USING THE `rm` COMMAND**! as you don't want to wipe out needed files on accident!!! Measure twice, cut once!

Comment: @wilhil Simplified, most of the configuration files are removed. Specifically, the system config files like the ones in /etc and places like that. apt-get doesn't always or usually doesn't delete files in your home folder so there may be some leftover files there if any.

Comment: Sorry, still not 100% clear (and sorry that this takes away from the original question)! e.g. Let's say I do apt-get install mypackage, and lets say that has a file called setup.sh which then writes /etc/mypackage.cfg, the /etc/mypackage.cfg is not know to apt-get or part of the original package... so, I am guessing `apt-get remove` will still keep the cfg file - I just don't get how `apt-get purge` knows to remove it... I guess I have to read up on package management in a lot more detail!

Answer (score 0):

Given the phrasing of your question I'm not sure if you are not actually asking for something still more detailed than this, but I'm just telling you what I know.

If you go to your [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/software-center/) and then click on the "history" icon, you should see everything you are seeking.  If there's something you aren't finding there, I'm extremely curious to know what it is.

Comment: Hi @Gyropyge - Thanks, but, I am actually trying to work without a GUI at this point and am trying to check more fundamental system changes... For example, I would love to freeze the system, muck around, and then perform a diff between the two stages. Software Center abstracts far too much and I wouldn't be able to see config/similar changes that have been made.

Comment: @wilhil, I can think of lots of valid reasons to work without a GUI, not the least of which would be the ability to backup the changes as an ascii file.  I get that.  But just as GUI-lubbers like us sometimes need to stray into the wilds of the terminal to accomplish something, I would think that if you were serious about analyzing a problem, you could actually tolerate the graphic appeal for several minutes at a time without your eyes actually bleeding.

Comment: I am actually trying to experiment right now with X and various other shells, so, using Ubuntu Software Centre really is a no-go. That aside, synaptic or even aptitude are more fit for purpose here, however, I am looking to look for changes made to the system after various packages are installed - not what packages are installed.

Comment: Just to be clear, I could always take a look at the Ubuntu Packages site, but, there are many applications that write config files (e.g. Heartbeat/pacemaker write the cib.xml files) that just aren't created until you run certain apps.... in addition, I have seen a few packages that have conflicting settings, so, I simply want to snapshot or similar and then compare the system later so I can study and learn.